# Добавление к таблице новых столбцов из других таблиц

Tags: sql

Пожалуйста натолкните на правильное решение, бьюсь уже второй день пробовал многое, одно из самых удачных было применение `MERGE`, но то ли я криво писал, то ли это все же не подходит.

Мне нужно создать временную таблицу, с определенными столбцами, и присоединять по одному новому столбцу по очереди(в зависимости от определенных задач)

ниже код который я писал для пробы. пробовал добавить столбец из таблицы на основе которой я и создавал временную. Но выходит ошибка

> multi-part identifiear "tempTable.column_new"

1)

```
 select col1, col2, ACCOUNT_RC
 into #account
 from TABLE1
```

2)

```
 alter table #account add ACCOUNT_RC_izmenen numeric(18,0)
```

3)

```
 MERGE #account AS tempTable  
    USING (SELECT ACCOUNT_RC + 1000000, ACCOUNT_RC from TABLE1)  as source (ACCOUNT_RC_izmenen, ACCOUNT_RC)
    ON (tempTable.ACCOUNT_RC = source.ACCOUNT_RC)  
    WHEN MATCHED THEN   
        UPDATE SET tempTable.column_new = source.ACCOUNT_RC_izmenen ;
```

Comment: дак добавили то вы `ACCOUNT_RC_izmenen `, а обращаетесь почему то к к полю `column_new` ?

Comment: мне почему то кажется, что данный `merge` аналогичен простому `update #account set ACCOUNT_RC_izmenen = ACCOUNT_RC_izmenen + 1000000`

Comment: ой, да это опечатка.. где добавление столбца не ACCOUNT_RC_izmenen numeric(18,0) а column_new numeric(18,0)

Comment: аналогичен, но это тестовый запрос, только для отработки технологии. потом буду добавлять столбцы из других таблиц

Comment: укажите просто `.... UPDATE SET column_new = source...` без `tempTable`, на это ведь и ругается.

Comment: ничего не исправилось.. да и скорее всего он бы просто обдейтил весь столбец значением из source, а не на каждую строку своё значение вставлял бы